# angular - filter all the objects that the startDate and EndDate is in range of month and year that was selected

Tags: javascript, date, angular-filters

I want to filter and get all the campaigns that are in range of the month and year that is being sent.
For example,
StartDate - 2/1/16
EndDate - 1/2/17
year - 2016
month - 4
I want this campaign to show on all the months from Feb' 2016 to Jan' 2017

```
app.filter('dateFilter', function () {
    return function (campaigns, year, month) {
        var filtered = [];
        if (!campaigns)
            return null;
        for (var i = 0; i < campaigns.length; i++) {
            var startDate = new Date(campaigns[i].startTime);
            var endDate = new Date(campaigns[i].endTime);

            if ( Validation )
                filtered.push(campaigns[i]);
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Comment: just use .getTime and Date.now to compare,

Comment: The month and year that is being send into the function is not the date.now. User can choose to filter the results by month and year. So Date.not won't help me.

Comment: Well, you can easily create a date like this: new Date('2015-01-01T18:00:00'), so you can get a timestamp with .getTime and then compare timestamps.

Comment: Also, it might be better using the map method of the array or the filter method in case you are using ES2015.
An ES2015 solution would look like
filtered = campaigns.filter(campaign => {
const filterDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-01T00:00:00`);
return campaigns[i].startTime < filterDate && campaigns[i].endTime > filterDate;
});
http://www.es6fiddle.net/ikbli17q/

Comment: For most people, 2/1/16 is 2 January.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the answer, it was pretty easy after all.
I just created the startDate and endDate with an empty day value and checked the range.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < campaigns.length; i++) {
            var startDate = new Date(campaigns[i].startTime);
            var endDate = new Date(campaigns[i].endTime);
            startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth());
            endDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth());
            var dateCheck = new Date(year, month - 1);
            if (dateCheck >= startDate && dateCheck <= endDate)
                filtered.push(campaigns[i]);
        }
```

Comment: In case startTime and endTime are timestamps, it can be done easier:

var filterDate = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-01T00:00:00").getTime();

if (campaigns[i].startTime < filterDate && campaigns[i].endTime > filterDate) ...